# React project - npm run build

Tags: reactjs, git, npm, web-deployment

I'm currently working on a create-react-app project. So, when I want to update the deployment, I just need to run npm run build in my local github repo, which will create a build folder in the project. then I copy and paste the build folder into my company's server folder (which I don't know how they set it up, to be honest). The application deployment will then be updated.
So, my concern is when I run "npm run build" in a specific branch, it also appears in other branch when I switch branches. My question is how this thing works. When branch is switched, the build folder is transferred and stays the same or will change according to the active brand.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the `build` folder is not tracked by `git` (it's not committed to GitHub). This means switching branches has no effect on the contents of the folder.

In other words, if you built on branch `a` and then switch to branch `b`, your build is still from the source code in branch `a`.

Comment: Hi Brian, Thank you so much for your quick answer. I also have another question. So, in case I ran "npm run build" in "A" branch, then I switch to "b" branch, then run "npm run build" in "b" branch, what will happen to the "build" folder?
Also, let say created build folder, but after that I made changes in my codes, then run "npm run build" again, will the build folder be updated? or I have to delete it and run npm run build again (which I'm doing and I find it inefficient)

Comment: It will overwrite any files with the same name in the next build. You usually do not need to delete the build folder in between. Unless you're experiencing a weird bug and then it may not be a bad idea to start fresh

Comment: That's perfect. I'm so scared of mixing up other branches with the production branch, and I'm the only one working on FE for this project. Your info is very helpful. Thank you so much Brian.